# Was Wicket W. Warrick named after Warwick Davis?

Tags: star-wars, history-of, names, actors, ewoks

[Wicket W. Warrick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wicket_W._Warrick) is an Ewok from the *Star Wars* universe.  The character first appeared in *Return of the Jedi* and was intended to be played by R2-D2 actor Kenny Baker.  However, Baker fell ill and was replaced on short notice by Warwick Davis.

Interestingly, the last name of the character is spelled similarly to, and pronounced the same as, the first name of the eventual actor.  Is this a coincidence, or was the character specifically named for Warwick Davis?  That is, what specific *out-of-universe* evidence do we have for the origin of the full name?

Also, I don't recall the character's full name being used *in-universe* in the *Return of the Jedi*, though I do remember it being used in the associated merchandising.  If it was ever used on-screen and in-universe (as opposed to, say, in the credits) in any film or TV series, what was the first time?  Or is the full name only known from text media (scripts, credit sequences, toys, novelizations, etc.)?

Answer (score 17):

**Actually it's a little more complicated (and interesting)**

According to the original [Starwars.com databank article on Wicket](https://web.archive.org/web/20101220062716/http://starwars.com/databank/character/wicketwwarrick/index.html) Warwick Davis was slated to play a background Ewok that the crew had named Warrick. When the actor playing Wicket (Kenny Baker) became ill Warwick, who'd caught the director's eye due to his ability to put his tongue through the vent hole in the mask and his trademark head-tilt, was then drafted in as a new character who they named "*Wicket[/]Warrick*" and the name stuck.

> **Behind the Scenes**
>
> The Ewok that befriends Leia was not always called
> Wicket, and did not always look the way he did. This principal Ewok
> was to be played by Kenny Baker, who also played Artoo-Detoo. On the
> day that Wicket's first scene was to be filmed, Baker took ill.
> Instead, the filmmakers used another Ewok, who was up to that point
> was named "Warrick."
>
> This new Ewok was played by a bright 11-year old named Warwick Davis.
> His character became Wicket W. Warrick, and Baker's Ewok was renamed
> Paploo, and later became the Ewok who would steal the speeder bike.
> Evidence of this change remains in the Marvel Comics adaptation of
> Jedi, which identifies the speeder thief as Wicket.

You might also be interested to note that the official novelisation (written after Warwick was cast but *before* principal production had been completed and Baker replaced) contains an ewok named [Warwick](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Warwick). It seems highly likely that *this* ewok was also named after Warwick Davis.

> Flattened down in the bushes on the ridge with the strike force were
> several Ewoks, including Wicket, Paploo, Teebo, and Warwick. The rest
> stayed lower, behind the knoll, out of sight.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars Episode VI: Return of the Jedi - Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_VI:_Return_of_the_Jedi_(novel))</sup></sub>

Comment: This turned out to be a much more interesting question/answer than I expected!

Comment: @Quasi_Stomach - There's some other interesting (but alas not especially relevant) bits about Warwick Davis in [Star Wars Insider #31](https://ibb.co/e51bVc)

Comment: "You **are** great!" (trips over own sword)

Comment: [Hey, it's what I do](https://i.imgur.com/09G4GzR.gif).

Comment: Although interesting about the origin of “Wicket”, I think this does not really answer the question about “Warrick” (or if it does, it's not clear) and this new information simply transfers the question: is it, or is it not, a coincidence that the “another Ewok” named “Warrick” was played by Warwick Davis? I think the statement in the answer (but not in the quoted part) that the name “Warrick” came from the crew lends credence to the theory that they had named this character “Warrick” after the actor playing it… but that's the question IMO.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR - It's very common for background characters to just be named after their actor.

Comment: @Valorum IMO that's useful information that could be in the answer. If I understand correctly, the chronological sequence is: (1) There was a background Ewok, played by Warwick Davis, who was named “Warrick”, and this name also occurs in the novelization. Because background characters are often named after their actor, it is “highly likely” (but not certain) that _this_ Ewok was indeed named after the actor. (2) When this actor was additionally cast as Wicket (after the incidents mentioned in the question), the name “Wicket Warrick” became the full name of Wicket.